# Typescript: generic return type based on function paramenter

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-eslint

Im trying to make a generic function that eventually makes a graphql query based on a "selectedFields" input to select specific fields of a full entity.

Ive made the type of "selectedFields" to be an array of keys of the generic type which is how the entity looks on the db table.
Now i want the result to have a type based on selectedFields.
Is it possible by any chance?
The code looks like that:

```
type KeysOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>[];

function query<DBEntity>(
    tableName: string,
    queryName: string,
    selectedFields: KeysOf<DBEntity>,
) {
    return this.apolloLink.execute({
        query: gql`
            query ${queryName} {
                ${queryName}: ${tableName} {
                    ${selectedFields.join('\n')}
                }
            }
        `
    }).map(
        result => result?.data[queryName] as ???
    );
}
```

NOTE: The "DBEntity" generic type is supposed to be a type for how the entity looks on db table
for some logics i havent shown here on this function.

Comment: Can you show us an example on how a specific `selectedFields` array would produce a return type? How would that return type look like?

Answer (score 0):

Given we don't know what the output of the `this.apolloLink.execute` is, something like this could work:

### Option 1

```js
type KeysOf<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>[];
type FieldNames = Record<string, string>
type YourResult<T> = { data: Record<string, KeysOf<T>> };
function query<DBEntity>(
    tableName: string,
    queryName: string,
    selectedFields: KeysOf<DBEntity>,
) {
    // replace '[{data: {}}]' with -> 'this.apolloLink.execute({ ...'
    const result: YourResult<DBEntity>[] = [{data: {}}]

    const output: KeysOf<DBEntity>[] = result.map(
        result => result?.data[queryName]
    );
    return output;

}
```

### Option 2

```js
type FieldNames = Record<string, string>
type YourResult<T> = { data: Record<string, keyof T> };
function query<DBEntity>(
    tableName: string,
    queryName: string,
    selectedFields: keyof DBEntity,
) {
    // replace '[{data: {}}]' with -> 'this.apolloLink.execute({ ...'
    const result: YourResult<DBEntity>[] = [{data: {}}]

    const output: (typeof selectedFields)[] = result.map(
        result => result?.data[queryName]
    );
    return output;

}
```

Comment: The output could be Partial<DBEntity> but isnt there a way to determine the output type by using the given selectedFields which are the actual keys that we select from db?

i thought there could be something like:
```
type x = {[K in keyof selectedFields]: DBEntity[K]}
const output = result.map(
        result => result?.data[queryName] as x
    );
```

The code above is just an example and will not compile of course :)

Comment: hmm maybe what you are looking for is: `const output: typeof selectedFields[] = result.map(...`

Comment: I added an Option 2 as well

Comment: The second one wont work since `typeof selectedFields` is an array unfortunately